# Open Containers in Remote SSH Hosts using VSCode

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

Using the [Remote Development](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack) extension pack, Visual Studio Code is able to open a Docker container running on the current system, and to open a folder on a remote host connected using SSH.

If there is a Docker container running on a remote SSH host, how can VSCode open a file/folder in this container?

Answer (score 16):

So you want to open a folder inside a container in a remote SSH server. Following are the steps through which I achieved it.

**Step 1**

install Remote Development extension in VSCode and open its control panel

[image]

**Step 2**

Connect VSCode to remote SSH server

[image]

**Step 3**

Upon connecting you'll notice a green tick sign, means you are connected to remote server, now select **Containers** from Remote Explorer dropdown. You'll see a list of containers. If you don't see the list of container or if you see list of local containers then follow along, otherwise move to **Step 4**.

[image]

**Step 3.1**

Add new context to your docker by executing following commands in terminal.

$ `docker context create my-remote-docker-machine --docker "host=ssh://username@host:port"`

$ `docker context ls`

$ `docker context use my-remote-docker-machine`

**Step 3.2**

$ `docker ps -a`

You'll notice that above command lists all the containers from remote server now (its because of the context which you just added)

Lets come back to VScode now, click on `Docker` from side bar menu, You'll notice a warning **Failed to connect. Is Docker Running?** [know more about this bug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docker/wiki/Troubleshooting#the-extension-does-not-find-docker-on-a-remote-machine-failed-to-connect-is-docker-installed-and-running-error)

[image]

**Troubleshooting**

> Verify that Docker extension is installed on the remote machine. As of
> February 2020 [there is a bug in VS Code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83675) that prevents the Docker
> extension to be installed remotely if it is already installed locally.
> This bug is scheduled to be fixed in VS Code 1.43 release. A
> workaround to get the extension installed remotely is [described here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docker/issues/1582#issuecomment-578882428).

- Uninstall Docker extension from VS Code. Close all VS Code windows.
- Start VS Code again. Use `Remote-SSH: Connect to Host..' to connect to remote machine.
- Open extension marketplace and install Docker extension on the remote machine (see screenshot below)

[image]

- Once the Docker extension is installed remotely, it can also be installed locally.

**Step 4**

From the containers list select the target container which you want your VSCode to connect to.

[image]

**Step 5**

Vala! VSCode is connected to the container inside remote server, you can click on Explorer and select any folder/directory inside container and start working in that directory.

[image]

Comment: Selecting 'Containers' in step3 lists down containers in the local machine and not on the remote machine. How can we list the containers of the remote-machine?

Comment: @AnoopK.Prabhu make sure your connection to remote server is successful

Comment: Yes it is. the green symbol is shown too. https://ibb.co/D1HW3Vw is what I see after the connection to remote machine is successful. Else I could find dockers in my local machine

Comment: @AnoopK.Prabhu so I found out that my docker host was set to remote already, that is the main reason it worked for me. But then I tried to reproduce your use-case by connecting to different remote server. I'm sharing my findings by updating the answer. Please have a look into it. Keenly waiting for the feedback.

Comment: The updated answer worked for me. 
Actually I had to do a bit of change for myself as the remote machine was behind a VPN which has a password and 2-step authentication. This made 'docker context' usage difficult. Port forwarding the docker.sock helped to deal with it.

Comment: Great!, @AnoopK.Prabhu feel free to accept this answer so that others can follow it too. Thanks.