# VSCode Remote Container ext on Linux

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I'm starting with containers (docker), I use Visual Studio Code but **Remote Container** extension is not showing up when I look for it.

- **VSCode:** 1.51.1
- **Node.js:** 12.14.1
- **Docker:** 19.03.13-ce
- **Docker-compose** 1.27.4
- **OS:** Linux x64 5.8.18-1-MANJARO

[Extension isn't showing up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4jD2.png)

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried to install it by its full name ?

Comment: ext install ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers (no success)

Comment: Hi zoid is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62592752/4453980) helpful?

Comment: No :( I can't install the remote containers extension...